# How do I change the column type (xtype) of a grid using Sencha Designer?

Tags: gridview, extjs, datagrid

I'm using Sencha's Ext Designer to create their [Cars example](http://www.sencha.com/learn/ext-designer-for-ext-js-4-users-guide), but I can't find the correct property to change the Price column so that it renders like a number.

[image]

The code behind it refers to an **xtype**, but this property is unavailable in the designer. There is also no way to edit the code in the designer tool.

How do I change the xtype of a column through the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Ext Designer Version: 1.2.2 Build: 48.

Right Click on the column in the grid, mouse over the Transform menu item and choose the type you need. I see the following choices:

- Ext.grid.column.Column
- Ext.grid.column.Action
- Ext.grid.column.Date
- Ext.grid.column.Number
- Ext.grid.column.Template